# Find a Database table's unique constraint

Tags: java, sql, oracle, unique, constraints

I'm trying to find the unique constraints of a table using Java (on an Oracle Database, but that should make no difference).

I found a way to discover the Primary Keys of a table, thanks to DatabaseMetaData's getPrimaryKeys(....);
However I was unable to find the unique constaints of the tables, and the Internet was not able to help me, therefore I'm ending here asking my question :)

Is there a clean way to find the unique constraints (or, rather, the name of the columns that must be unique for a table.. Well you get it hehe) of a table ? 
Best regards,

Nils

Comment: So I gather you'd rather not have an Oracle-specific solution?

Answer (score 20):

you can query the data dictionary:

```
SQL> SELECT cc.*
  2    FROM all_constraints c
  3    JOIN all_cons_columns cc ON (c.owner = cc.owner
  4                             AND c.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name)
  5   WHERE c.constraint_type = 'U'
  6     AND c.table_name = 'T';

OWNER      CONSTRAINT_NAME   TABLE_NAME     COLUMN_NAME     POSITION
---------- ----------------- -------------- ------------- ----------
VNZ        UNIQUE_COL        T              COLUMN1                1
VNZ        UNIQUE_COL        T              COLUMN2                2
VNZ        UNIQUE_COL2       T              COLUMN2                1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since most databases store these constraints as an index, you can use [DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean)) as previously mentioned. This worked well for me when using **Postgresql**.

It's only important to call `getIndexInfo()` with the 4th parameter as `true` as the documenation says:

> `unique` - when true, return only indices for unique values; when false,
>   return indices regardless of whether unique or not

With the following code:

```
// Class to combine all columns for the same index into one object
public static class UniqueConstraint {
    public String table;
    public String name;
    public List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s] %s: %s", table, name, columns);
    }
}

public static List<UniqueConstraint> getUniqueConstraints(Connection conn, String schema, String table) throws SQLException {
    Map<String, UniqueConstraint> constraints = new HashMap<>();

    DatabaseMetaData dm = conn.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs = dm.getIndexInfo(null, schema, table, true, true);
    while(rs.next()) {
        String indexName = rs.getString("index_name");
        String columnName = rs.getString("column_name");

        UniqueConstraint constraint = new UniqueConstraint();
        constraint.table = table;
        constraint.name = indexName;
        constraint.columns.add(columnName);

        constraints.compute(indexName, (key, value) -> {
            if (value == null) { return constraint; }
            value.columns.add(columnName);
            return value;
        });
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(constraints.values());
}
```

you can call:

```
getUniqueConstraints(conn, "public", tableName);
```

and get back a list of all the unique constraints for a given table. The constraints are grouped by index since one index can cover multiple columns if they are only unique in combination.

Answer (score 0):

If Oracle creates indexes for unique constraints (I don't know if it does, you need to check) than you could find out about your constraints via `getIndexInfo()`

Comment: Yes, Oracle creates a unique index on any column(s) identified in a UNIQUE constraint - that's how it enforces uniqueness.

Comment: However, unique indexes may be completely Oracle-centric. If a generic solution is needed, this may not be true in all cases.

Comment: And, I think Oracle can also use a non-unique index to enforce a unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Unique constraints are usually enforced by a index. Perhaps use `DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo()` to find the indexes where the non-unique is false?