# How to get the unique columns from a given table?

Tags: java, jdbc

Lets say I have a table called `"person"` and it has 4 columns (name, last_name, city, pincode). Two of those columns (name, last_name) are unique columns. I want to get these two columns from the JDBC driver. How can I get this information from a JDBC driver?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/48042309/6170711

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find information about unique columns (defined as constraints or unique indexes), using [`DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,boolean)), passing `true` for the fourth parameter (`unique`).

For example

```java
DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
// NOTE: You may need to use "PERSON"
try (ResultSet rs = md.getIndexInfo(null, null, "person", true, true)) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        String indexName = rs.getString("INDEX_NAME");
        String columnName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
        if (indexName == null || columnName == null) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", indexName, columnName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a simple example based on MySql:

```
public class Test {
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDatabase";
static final String USER = "----";
static final String PASS = "somePass";
static final String QUERY = "SHOW KEYS FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'\n";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Open a connection
    final ArrayList<String> primaryKeyColumns = new ArrayList<>();
    try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            primaryKeyColumns.add(rs.getString(5));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(primaryKeyColumns);
}
```

}

Look at the used query in this way you can fetch more specific information.